# Parse JSON with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two JSON returns.

One I am able to parse fine

```
{"login"=>"foo", "id"=>bar,
```

with

```
@foobar_collect["login"]
```

But one I am having issues with

```
{"items"=>[{"user_id"=>foo, "user_type"=>"bar",
```

I try

```
@foobar_collect["items"]["user_id"]
```

And it gives me an error `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did either of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foobar_collect["items"].first["user_id"]
```

Comment: Is there a difference between "" and '' and what is the difference between .first and [0]

Comment: @Elementmindfreak No meaningful different between `.first` and `[0]` in this case. Double-quoted strings are interpolated, single-quoted strings aren't.

Comment: @Elementmindfreak to expound upon @DaveNewton's answer: interpolation means you can evaluate an expression inside a double-quoted string using `#{...}`. For example: `name = 'Pete'; puts "Hello, #{name}" # => 'Hello, Pete!'`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
@foobar_collect['items'][0]['user_id']
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is `@foobar_collect['items']` is an array.

Comment: Is there a difference between "" and '' and what is the difference between .first and [0]

Comment: no there's no difference, i only use double quotes when a string has a ruby code inside the string like `"asd#{1 + 1}asd"`.  `[0]` and `.first` is also the same but I prefer `[0]` since it's easier to read  and easier to get other elements of the array.